# PHP Query and div class

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I really need some help. I am trying to build a website and pull content from a mysql database.
The div I am trying to populate is below. The problem I have is how do I incorporate the php code into the div?

```
<div class="cardetails">
    <img src="img/carpic.jpg"/>
    <p class="make"><a href="car.html">'model of car'<a></p>
    <p class="price">£Price</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>


$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Password1")
    or die ("Couldn't connect to Server!");
$result = mysql_select_db("my_cars", $db)
    or die ("Couldn't select Database!");
$query = "select img, make, price, from tbl_automatic WHERE MakeID = '7'";
$result = mysql_query($query,$db)
    or die ("Couldn't execute query!");
```

Thanking you all in advance

Comment: Let me get it stright, you want to post query information/details in a div?

Comment: Please don't use any `mysql_` functions as they are deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Or mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Hi Evceyone, thanks for getting back to me. Sorry for late reply, I had to take a break as it was "doing my head in".

Comment: Yotam, yes that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Guys, I must also point out that this is the first time I have every played with websites and php. You can say that I am but a Padawan and you are the Masters

Comment: @grimm1 You need to loop over the database results and add the data to the HTML - see how the two answers below use a while loop to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Password1")
    or die ("Couldn't connect to Server!");
$result = mysql_select_db("my_cars", $db)
    or die ("Couldn't select Database!");
$query = "select img, make, price, from tbl_automatic WHERE MakeID = '7'";
$result = mysql_query($query,$db)
    or die ("Couldn't execute query!");

while($q = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<div class="cardetails">
    <img src="<?=$q['img']?>"/>
    <p class="make"><a href="car.html"><?=$q['make']?><a></p>
    <p class="price"><?=$q['price']?></p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Hi neeagl,
Sorry for late reply. Many thanks for your solution, unfortunately nothing is being pulled into the page.
If I run the query in phpMyadmin, it returns the correct information. Any further help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please paste content of your page by doing view-source? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

neeagl beat me to it but here's mine anyhow. As mentioned in the comments it's best to use mysqli or pdo now.

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Password1")
    or die ("Couldn't connect to Server!");
$result = mysql_select_db("my_cars", $db)
    or die ("Couldn't select Database!");
$query = "select img, make, price, from tbl_automatic WHERE MakeID = '7'";
$result = mysql_query($query,$db)
    or die ("Couldn't execute query!");


$cardetails = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$cardetails .= '
<div class="cardetails">
    <img src="img/'.$row['img'].'"/>
    <p class="make"><a href="car.html">'.$row['make'].'<a></p>
    <p class="price">£'.$row['price'].'Price</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>';
}

echo $cardetails;
```

Comment: Hi logic-unit, Many thanks for your input. You mention mysqli or pdo unfortunately, I am not sure how to do that as I am new to all of this. Any guidance is much appreciated.